# return multiple columns from stored procedure in MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Was previously using this line in my controler to return an id and text column from, a stored procedfure in asp.net MVC

```
user = new SelectList(ctx.Database.SqlQuery<LkUpGenderModel>("EXEC dbo.uspGetLkUpGender").ToList(), "GenderID", "Gender");
```

However i now want to return more text values, I have extended the model to have these extra fields but I'm getting an error.

Is there a way to get this working:

```
user = new SelectList(ctx.Database.SqlQuery<LkUpGenderModel>("EXEC dbo.uspGetLkUpGender").ToList(), "GenderID", "Gender", "GenderShort", "GenderCombined");
```

currently it flags the SelectList( saying the call is ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

The previous code simply returns instances of `LkUpGenderModel` and then builds a `SelectList` from that using the `GenderID` property of that class as the value and the `Gender` property as the display text.

Your new code doesn't request more properties, it simply passes additional parameters to the `SelectList` constructor: namely, `dataGroupField` which you're setting to the `GenderShort` property, and `selectedValue`, which you're setting to the `GenderCombined` property. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725507(v=vs.118).aspx.

If you have additional columns being returned from the stored procedure that you want filled in on the class, then you should add additional properties to the class to handle those. However, since all you're doing with the data is creating a `SelectList` from it, you can't send any additional data to the view other than the value and display text, making returning additional data pointless in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.  How would I go about changing this to return additional columns from the procedure to pass to the view?

Comment: You would need to pass it back to the view in something other than a `SelectList`.